# High Frequency Excitation on Class D Amplifier

Tags: pcb, decoupling-capacitor, oscillation, class-d

I'm building a discretized class D audio amplifier that's running at 250kHz that's designed to run on a single ended 80V supply. I was seeing very high amplitude, high frequency excitations on the output that actually damaged the driving FETs. I ran it on a lower voltage and saw them as well, here's the output of the FETs running on 20V (channel 2):

[image]

These seem to be at around 15MHz. I originally thought this was a bypassing problem, since I had no ceramic caps bypassing power, only about 3mF of electrolytics. Throwing a few uF value ceramic caps at the problem didn't seem to attenuate the excitations noticeably, should I just add a lot more ceramic caps?

Comment: Where's the very high amplitude? You mean that 4V of ringing on top of the 20V square wave?

Comment: Yes, the ringing isn't very large at 20V but becomes something like 30V ringing at 80V, which can damage the FETs.

Comment: You might look over this from TI: [Ringing reduction](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slpa010/slpa010.pdf). (I assume you aren't having scope probe issues and know how to set that up okay. Certainly, without the probe you were still having troubles. So it's reasonable to look elsewhere than your probing technique... for now.)

Comment: The proper diode/RC snubber across the transformer primary should reduce those peaks by -3dB. Assuming your scope probes are not part of the problem.

Comment: Are you using a GROUND PLANE? Show your PCB layout, and where the FETs are connected, so we can determine the FET lead inductances.

Comment: Scheamtic, schematic, schematic.

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect your FET **failure was from cross conduction** ( aka shoot-thru) and lack of dead-band which created heavy current spikes and that triggered induction ringing in faulty probe measurement method giving the illusion of overvoltage.

If your probe ground lead is 100 mm long then it will be about 100nH and the coaxial 10:1 probe capacitance of 75'ish pF/m resonates in the 20MHz region. So keep gnd connection < 1cm without clips ground wire using tip and barrel. then the true flat BW of the impedance-matched probe can occur. *( search here or web for Tek probe spring)*

Now at 80V your parasitic trace inductance and capacitance adds another resonance that must be dampened with a series R due to mismatched impedance load to low Rds, high Coss switch when drain coil is switched off.

What is the deadtime in your C-MOSFET bridge? It is this time when stray reactance resonates and minimizing Q is critical for ringing. Often Ferrite sleeves or SMD beads are used to absorb ringing but inherent shunt resistance of lossy beads. Consider impedance matching methods.  Low inductance grounding is also critical using braid or Litz wire or low L/W ratio tracks and also high self resonant frequency L.

So generally slowing down high side turn on with a matched Series R to gate resistance and using a low ESR diode to turn off such that T=R*Ciss is slower turning on than off creates dead-time of 0.5us or more may fix shoot thru, but this timing is affected by Vgs,  V+ and junction temp.